# How do I have a fail safe command in python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a program that randomly places my mouse in specific areas in python, and I'm still testing it so it can get a bit crazy.  I was wondering if it were possible to make a fail safe command that would terminate the program if the key or command were entered.

Since the program is clicking and moving around on another window on my computer it deselects the window python is running in, which make the "Keyboard Interrupt" fail to work.

Here's the program:

```
import pyautogui
import random
import time
time.sleep(6)#gives you time to click the right window

try:
    while True:    
        x = random.randint(239, 1536)  #randomizes the position of the mouse

        pyautogui.moveTo(x,663)        #moves the mouse to position

        pyautogui.doubleClick()        #fires the gun in game twise   

        time.sleep(1)                  #gives time for the game to 
        pyautogui.doubleClick()        #catch up with the mouse and fires gun

        pyautogui.doubleClick()        #fires gun twice again                                

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('Yup')
```

And if there is anything wrong with the way I'm coding please tell me.  I'm still new to coding so any tips would be awesome.

Comment: So, are you looking to kill your program if you get a Keyboard Initerrupt exception? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. If the program goes bonkers and I can't control it(which happens a lot) I need a way to exit without having to use the mouse.

Comment: You can replace the `while True` with a counter and have it loop a fixed number of times.

Comment: @MalachiBazar Can you restrict the mouse movement to current window only?

Comment: @shanmuga I'm not sure, but the pyautogui website doesn't say anything specifically. Here's the link https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Keith I don't really want to restrict it to a limited amount of time because I want it to move while I'm not at the computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking to do is use a [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in your Exception.

Try this:

```
import sys

try:
    # all your code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Will this still be effective if I am having pyautogui execute keyboard controls too? Or will the keyboard controls trigger the exit?

Answer (score 15):

PyAutoGUI also has a fail-safe feature. Moving the mouse cursor to the upper-left corner
of the screen will cause PyAutoGUI to raise the pyautogui.FailSafeException
exception.

Your program can either handle this exception with try and except statements
or let the exception crash your program. Either way, the fail-safe feature will stop the
program if you quickly move the mouse as far up and left as you can.

```
>>>import pyautogui
>>>pyautogui.FAILSAFE= True
```

By default FAILSAFE is True, and you can also disable it.

```
>>>pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

Comment: why pygui has such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

this should work, whenever you click the key it will break the loop, install the module keyboard with

```
pip install keyboard
```

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    break
```

Comment: It would be better if you could import keyboard....

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)