# How to break out of an endless loop with a key press detected in the background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, keyboardinterrupt

So I have a script called `clicker.py`. All this program does is click one one spot forever. My problem is, how can I kill this program? I can't switch to the command prompt window to press `CTRL + C` on my keyboard to make the script get a `KeyboardInterrupt` because `clicker.py` will just click out of the command prompt window.

How can I make it so, if I press the `esc` key on my keyboard, it breaks out of the loop? It needs to detect basically all keystrokes in the background.

---

[image]

As soon as I run the script. It **spam** clicks the blue area (in the picture). As soon as it clicks that blue area, the command prompt window is no longer on top. Now I can't access the command prompt window because if I try to switch the window, it'll click in the blue area and the photoshop window will be on top again.

---

clicker.py

```
import pyautogui

print("Welcome")    

while(1):
    pyautogui.click(x=100, y=100, button="left")
    # If esc is pressed break out of loop (You don't need to press esc in the command window. Just press esc)

print("Bye! See you next time")
```

---

I tried this (but it didn't work because you have to press `esc` while you have the command prompt window up

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

print("Welcome")    

while(1):
    pyautogui.click(x=100, y=100, button="left")
    if (keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        print("exiting loop")
        break

print("Bye! See you next time")
```

Comment: ctrl-c didnt work ?you can always kill it using task manager(ctrl+alt+del) or ps kill

Comment: @VenkataSriHarshaVemuluru Sorry Edited question to make more sense. I can do `CTRL+C`. But imagine running this program. If it clicks in one spot without a delay, how  can I possible go to my command prompt window in time and press `CTRL + C`. Its humanly impossilbe for me to switch to my command prompt window and press `CTRL + C` before the script clicks again. If the program clicks, it clicks out of the command prompt window (hence minimizing that window again)

Comment: Try take your mouse to the left upper corner!

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I know `PyAutoGUI` has that fail safe, but how can I do that, when the mouse is being click constantly on one spot (far away from the upper left corner)

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182221/how-do-i-have-a-fail-safe-command-in-python

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Yes I have. Like I said, I can't access the command prompt. So I can't press `CTRL+C`. I added a picture to the question to make it easier to understand