# How to stop or pause pyautogui at any moment that I want?

Tags: python, pandas, database, pyautogui

I am building some macro program using pyautogui.

Unfortunately I am not able to stop for-loop so sometimes it takes too much time until for-loop end.
Is there any way to stop the program at any moment I want? or I just wait until program end.

### below is my code

```
CURRENT_DIR = os.getcwd()
list = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR,'BOM_list.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(list)

for i in df['MLFB'].index:
    MLFB = df.loc[i, 'MLFB']
    print(MLFB)
    a = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('a_material.png')
    print(a)
    pyautogui.moveTo(a)
    pyautogui.moveRel(350, 0)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press('a')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    pyautogui.typewrite(MLFB)
    b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('b_execute.png')
    print(b)
    pyautogui.moveTo(b)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
    pyautogui.press('y')
    pyautogui.press('t')
    pyautogui.press('a')
    pyautogui.press('i')
    pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('down')
    pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
    time.sleep(2)

    c = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('c_Directory.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(c)
    pyautogui.moveRel(350, 0)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press('a')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    pyautogui.typewrite(CURRENT_DIR)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    d = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('d_Filename.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(d)
    pyautogui.moveRel(350, 0)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press('left')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')

    pyautogui.typewrite(MLFB)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
    time.sleep(2)

    e = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('e_go_back.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(e)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: omg, this is next level hacking

Comment: I think this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182221/how-do-i-have-a-fail-safe-command-in-python). Or I think you should simply log out of your computer to stop the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyAutoGUI has a built in failsafe to terminate the program at any time. Just move your mouse to the top left corner of your main monitor where your x, y values would be 0, 0.

Typing `print(pyautogui.FAILSAFE)` should return `True`, telling us the failsafe is on. You could also disable it if it's getting in the way of your program by setting it to `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False`

Looking through your code, you could save some space by using [hotkey()](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function) when you want to press more than one key at a time:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('a')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```

Is the same as:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
```

You could also check out [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) which allows you to run more than one process at a time.

The following code will have an example main program running and when the `Esc` key is pressed, the main program will pause and the user is prompted if they want to continue or not.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from pynput import keyboard


def exit_program():
    def on_press(key):
        if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
            main.status = 'pause'
            user_input = input('Program paused, would you like to continue? (y/n) ')

            while user_input != 'y' and user_input != 'n':
                user_input = input('Incorrect input, try either "y" or "n" ')

            if user_input == 'y':
                main.status = 'run'
            elif user_input == 'n':
                main.status = 'exit'
                exit()

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()


def main():
    main.status = 'run'

    while True:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(1)

        while main.status == 'pause':
            time.sleep(1)

        if main.status == 'exit':
            print('Main program closing')
            break


Thread(target=main).start()
Thread(target=exit_program).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

[The answer.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjgD2.gif)

This is how I stop the pyautogui animation at any instance provided I don't interfere with the `pyautogui.FAILSAFE` option