# Break out of while loop while in another module

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to make a controlled while loop to stop explorer.exe (python)

My module code:

```
import os
import time
locked = "nullstate"
print(locked)
def Lock(tm_mi):
    t_end = time.time() + 60 * tm_mi
    while time.time() < t_end:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        tasklist = os.popen("tasklist")
        tasklist = tasklist.read()
        if "explorer.exe" in tasklist:
            os.system("taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F")
    
def Unlock():
    os.system("explorer.exe")


def Start(tm_mi):
    print(locked)
    if locked == True:
        t_end = time.time() + 60 * tm_mi
        while time.time() < t_end:
            print("wloop")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            tasklist = os.popen("tasklist")
            tasklist = tasklist.read()
            if locked == False:
                print("we did get here")
            if "explorer.exe" in tasklist:
                os.system("taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F")
        Unlock()
```

My controller code:

```
from lock_api import lock_api
import time

lock_api.locked = True
lock_api.Start(0.1)
lock_api.locked = False
```

I tried to change the "locked" varible with no avail

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Andrew Stone as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068775/how-to-stop-or-pause-pyautogui-at-any-moment-that-i-want). Here is how you can stop the while loop on a key press (if you want to exit the program by changing the locked variable to false, change `if locked == True` to `while locked is True` AND make the `Start` function an [asynchronous function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5Bo1Je9EmE)).

```
import sys
import threading

import keyboard

# change what key stops the program
PUASE_ON_KEY = "esc"


def exit_program():
    def on_keyboard_press(key):
        if key.name == PUASE_ON_KEY:
            main.status = "pause"

            user_input = input("Program paused, would you like to continue? (y/n): ")

            while user_input not in ["y", "n"]:
                user_input = input("Incorrect input, try either 'y' or 'n': ")

            if user_input == "y":
                main.status = "run"
            elif user_input == "n":
                main.status = "exit"
                sys.exit()

    keyboard.on_press(on_keyboard_press)


def main(tm_mi):
    main.status = "run"
    print(locked)
    if locked == True:
        t_end = time.time() + 60 * tm_mi
        while time.time() < t_end and main.status == "run":
            while main.status == "pause":
                pass
            print("wloop")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            tasklist = os.popen("tasklist")
            tasklist = tasklist.read()
            if locked == False:
                print("we did get here")
            if "explorer.exe" in tasklist:
                os.system("taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F")

        print("Main program exiting")
        Unlock()  # I am assuming you want to run this function when exiting.


threading.Thread(target=main).start()
threading.Thread(target=exit_program).start()
```

Comment: I want to be able to break out of the loop at any given time