# Exiting out of a running Python script when script window is hidden

Tags: mouse, pyautogui, terminate

I have a Python script written using Visual Studio Code that periodically moves the mouse icon to keep the computer active and stop it from falling asleep. This computer is used for displaying other info, so when the program is running the script window is minimized and another window is selected and opened and then the computer is left alone. When I want to use the computer again the Ctrl+C keyboard interrupt to terminate the script does not work unless the script window is reopened. This proved to be annoying as the script takes control of the mouse away from the user. I have a 'time.sleep' command that pauses the mouse movement to allow for user control again for a bit, but I would like to be ab le to just exit the script without having to wait for this pause to be able to open up the script window.

I am fairly new to Python, so I am unsure of other commands or keyboard inputs that might allow this to be possible.

The code I have does utilize the pyautogui module and has the default failsafe of moving the mouse icon to the corner of the screen enabled. However, this still requires me to wait for the pause in the script when I have control of the mouse again.

This is for a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pyautogui, just quickly move your mouse to the top left corner of the screen and your program will stop

Comment: Do you know of another way? I am unable to control the mouse enough to move it to the top left corner of the screen while the script is running. I have to wait for the pause I implemented before I have control again.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. Just choose a specific key and press it and program will stop
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65351588/16493039